# php function for sql query doesn't work - 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

my code doesn't works ... it returns only a 500 error :(

```
function getfromdb($select, $tablenme, $wherewhat, $whereval) { 

  $msntps = $conn->query("SELECT $select FROM $tablenme WHERE $wherewhat = '$whereval'")->fetch_object()->$selectval; 
  return $msntps;
}
```

and then i would like get something with

```
echo getfromdb("email", "users", "username", "testusername");
```

Comment: you have to pass `$conn`  also as a parameter

Comment: how :o   __________

Comment: you need to search PDO tutorials for accessing data from db. you will get some good and easy to understand example

Comment: but `echo $conn->query("SELECT something FROM testtable WHERE username = 'testuser'")->fetch_object()->something;` still works ..

Comment: and btw i use mysqli `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: `function getfromdb($select, $tablenme, $wherewhat, $whereval,$conn) { `